Working with vscode, I am looking for a simple compiler for js code (like "Live Sass Compiler" Extension)
My Team is working with vscode. But the majority of them are no devs. We use Live Sass Compiler for scss files and need a similar solution for js files. The config and setup have to be as simple as possible. i dont want to use webstack, since it will come up with versioning problems sooner or later. i need the most simple solution for this possible.
i tried making a "pipeline" with Run On Save, babel and minifyAll, but could not get it to work unless i installed the extensions via console. but that would be way to complicated for the majority of my colleagues.
